What is the smallest binary number of $4$ bit? Is it $(0000)_2$ or $(1000)_2$?
Problem: What is the smallest binary number of $4$ bit?
My approach: Today, my teacher asked me that and I replied $(1000)_2$ but my teacher said that it will be $(0000)_2$. If I ask someone what is the smallest decimal value of $2$ digits, everyone will say $10$. Will anyone say $00$?
Decimal and binary is the exact same thing except the "Digits Concept" (binary has $2$ digits and decimal has $10$ digits etc).
I said that $(010)_2$ will be considered as $2$ bit. But my teacher is saying that the zero of binary and the zero of decimal is not the same.
Question: Who is correct? You have to explain too. Help me.

These are all conventions, not matters of right and wrong. Your teacher's conventions are not consistent from binary to decimal, but conventions don't have to be consistent across domains. So long as everyone is upfront on what conventions they are using, everything's OK.

This seems more like a problem of language. Maybe 'a 4-bit number' is different from 'a 2-digit number'

I didn't understand

In addition to fixed conventions, this is also highly sensitive to context and subtleties in English wording. If the question is "what is the smallest number you can form with four bits?", the answer is zero. If the context is that we're showing bigger and bigger numbers and including zero would obviously be redundant, then "the smallest four bit number" would indeed be eight. If the context is computing or otherwise counting or encoding with bit strings, then 0000 is likely "the smallest four bit value", etc.

But $0000_2=0_2$ which is $1$ bit. we will say $010$ a $2$ bit because the zero of the left side is exclusive. So $0000$ is $1$ bit.

While I agree that language, usage, and convention make a question of "which is correct" impossible and meaningless, I also know there are a lot of ignorant instructors out there who in a fair universe would have no business teaching mathematics.  I think you instructor is one.  The comment about the 0 of binary and decimal being different sounds like gobbledigook.  And if the teacher has a reason they should be considered to be different in concept he should have been able to express it better to a student.  I suspect your teacher is an ignoramus.

That said though "What is the smallest binary number of 4 bit?" seems to me to be an ambiguous question as to what it actually means and can have different answer based one. It could be "what is the smallest number expressible in four bits" which is $0$.You can argue "but wouldn't that mean the smallest number with two digits is $0$" and maybe I could "expressible in four bits, expressible with a committed two digit allocation"(both $0$0) is different than "smallest of variable lenghth with 4 bits, or 2 digits". ($1000,10$ for both). But if I meant that, I should be able to explain that.

I think your thoughts about the answer are in agreement with my answer , @fleablood , while our thoughts about the instructor match too , I settled with "wording given by the teacher seems a little odd" to avoid being blunt there !

I think the correct but not very satisfactory answer is that it's a question of convention. But I think we can still decide, depending whether we're talking about mathematics or computer science.
In mathematics, 10 and 010 are equal, so they must be indistinguishable in terms of their mathematical properties. If we want the notion of ‘number of digits’ to have a mathematical meaning, then there must exists some function $f$ such that $f(x)$ is the number of digits of $x$. Since $10=010$, we must have $f(10)=f(010)$, so 10 and 010 have the same number of digits, which should be 2. For the same reason, 00 is a 1-digit number, not a 2-digit number.
If we want to consider 010 as a 3-digit number, then I think we're out of mathematics. I don't think a mathematical concept should depend on how you write mathematics. Unless, of course, we're into the study of writing itself (stories of meta-language, etc.), but I think that's going a bit beyond the scope of the question.
On the other hand, in computing, there is the fundamental question of information storage. A bit has a mathematical definition (written in base 2), but it also has a physical meaning. There are computer languages that allocate a certain amount of space to the storage of a number. For example, a short int, ranging from 0 to 15, can be stored on 4 bits, whatever its value. In this case, 0 is stored as 0000, which is the smallest 4-bit number.

You are saying $1000$ is correct(math).

I think OP wants to leave out Computers Stuff.

@Prem Yes. I don't need to discuss about computer.

I am saying both can be correct depending on the definition you choose. But in maths, I think it makes more sense to say the answer is 1000. That is my opinion, based on the argument I wrote in my answer, I am not saying it is a fact.

There is no way to know who is right. In Mathematics , we use Definitions to then make Claims. When Definition is Consistent with Claim , it is right. Else it is wrong.
Consider this Example before we move to your Decimal+Binary Query :
Is Zero a Natural Number ?
Definition 1 : Natural Numbers are $N_1=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$
I will then claim that no , Zero is not Natural.
Definition 1 : Natural Numbers are $N_0=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots\}$
I will then claim that yes , Zero is Natural.
Which is right ? Both are right.
When I use Def 1 to say Zero is Natural or I use Def 2 to say Zero is not Natural , then the claim is wrong : It is not Consistent with Definition.
Coming to your Decimal+Binary Query :
Def X : A number with representation $X_1X_2X_3 \cdots X_n$ is said to have $n$ Digits only when $X_1$ is not Zero , otherwise it will have less than $n$ Digits.
Def Y : A number with representation $Y_1Y_2Y_3 \cdots Y_n$ is said to have $n$ Digits even when $Y_1$ is Zero.
According to Def X , $1000$ is the smallest 4 Digit number.
According to Def Y , $0000$ is the smallest 4 Digit number.
Which is right ? Both are right according to Consistency with Definitions.
When I use Def X to claim $0000$ is smallest or I use Def Y to claim $1000$ is smallest , I will be wrong : I am not Consistent with Definition.
ADDENDUM :
(1) Here the wording given by the teacher seems a little odd.
"my teacher is saying that the zero of binary and the zero of decimal is not the same"
That is not generally true in terms of writing numbers.
All Zeros are SAME.
(2) There is a Context/Way where what the teacher said is right , though the teacher in speaking very loosely.
In Computer Systems , Memory is measured in Bits , where a Byte is Eight Bits.
Whether we use it or not , those Bits inside a Memory Byte are always in use by the Electronics Circuitry.
In that Case , we learn to represent numbers in Sequences of Bytes where we can use 1s Complement , 2s Complement , gray code , BCD , ASCII , what-ever.
There all Bits are always used , always written.
Hence $0000$ is indeed the smallest 4 Bit number within that Context/Way.
When we use some other "Encoding" , $-7$ is the smallest 4 Bit number , while $+8$ is the largest 4 Bit number.
Maybe the teacher was not aware of that , hence the teacher used the wrong wording.
Maybe the teacher was indeed aware of that , though the Students were not yet at the level to know more , hence the teacher used the wrong wording.

Please, ignore Computer Systems.

Talk about pure math.

I wanted to make the answer "Complete" , unlike the teacher. You should , of course , focus on the Math Part , while ignoring the Addendum covering Computers.

What is the correct answer(Math)? You analyzed computers too.

The answer I already gave was "Which is right ? Both are right according to Consistency with Definitions." using just Pure Math [[ You should just ignore the ADDENDUM , which is there to make the answer "Complete" , making it more useful in general ]]
